# Quartiles in SAS included incorrect number of observations

Tags: sas

I am trying to calculate the quartiles of the data in SAS code using the following code:

```
PROC RANK data = final_states out = final_states percent;
    var poverty_rate;
    ranks pov_percentile;
    var semi_poverty_rate;
    ranks semi_pov_percentile;
RUN;

/*Create quartiles for poverty percentiles*/
DATA final_states; 
    set final_states;
    if pov_percentile <= 25 then pov_quart = 1;
    else if pov_percentile > 25 and pov_percentile <= 50 then pov_quart = 2;
    else if pov_percentile > 50 and pov_percentile <= 75 then pov_quart = 3;
    else pov_quart = 4;
RUN;
```

After running the code, I ran a tabulate command using the following:

```
PROC FREQ final_states;
    tables pov_quart;
RUN;
```

I got the following results:

```
pov_quart  Frequency
1          865
2          785
3          785
4          785
```

Is there something wrong with my code that produced these results?

Comment: Do you have a lot of ties, possibly at 0 or another small number?

Comment: I checked this using PROC SQL and there minimum for the 1st quartile is greater than 0. I did notice that the maximum for the first quartile is 10.59 while the minimum for the second quartile is 10.60. Is it possibly a significant figure issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check for missing.

```
DATA final_states; 
    set final_states;
    if not missing(pov_percentile) then do;
       if pov_percentile <= 25 then pov_quart = 1;
       else if pov_percentile > 25 and pov_percentile <= 50 then pov_quart = 2;
       else if pov_percentile > 50 and pov_percentile <= 75 then pov_quart = 3;
       else pov_quart = 4;
       end;
RUN;
```

Comment: I tried this code and I am still getting the same distribution across both variables.

Comment: @hpr You keep reusing FINAL_STATES and I'm guessing that POV_QUART is left over from previous run, assuming that you do have missing values.